# typecasting and reference in c++

Tags: c++, casting, lvalue, rvalue

Please look at the following call and the corresponding function,

```
long pagenumber = 0;
Node *newNode = createNode();
bufMgr->writePage(pageNumber,(char*)newNode);
```

and writePage is declared as follows

```
writePage(long &pageNumber,char* &node)
```

writePage accepts a long reference and char* reference.
The above doesn't compile, It shows the following error

```
no matching function for call to ‘SampleBufferManager::writePage(long int&, char*)’
SampleBufferManager.h:28: note: candidates are: bool SampleBufferManager::writePage(long int&, char*&)
```

Can anyone help me out, how to handle this...The typecast is doing the problem, and the code compiles if i do it in the following way:

```
long pagenumber = 0;
Node *newNode = createNode();
char *test = (char*)newNode;
bufMgr->writePage(pageNumber,test);
```

How could the problem be solved??

Comment: You've already solved the problem of how to pass the reference. There may be other problems with this implementation though ;-)

Comment: Wait, so why do you not want to create a variable? That's the only way you can do it; it won't work as it is now with just a cast. (See Oli's answer if the function doesn't need to modify the `char*`, in which case you don't need to create a variable)

Comment: The issue here is: what does this function do WRT `char`? Should this function really take a `Node *&`? Can you fix it?

Answer (score 3):

You can't pass a reference to a <strike>temporary</strike> rvalue (thanks curiousguy). You'll have to make a variable and pass that:

```
char* c = (char*)newNode;
bufMgr->writePage(pageNumber, c);
```

Comment: or alter the function as Oli observed.

Comment: You can't pass a _non-const_ reference to a temporary. Fix'd.

Comment: @Griwes a reference is a non-const reference.

Comment: @SethCarnegie: but you can pass const reference - and, from your answer, OP can read "I cannot pass any kind of reference to a temporary".

Comment: Technical side node: "_temporary_" Actually, there is no temporary here!

Comment: @curiousguy ah now that I think about it, you're right. What would it be called, passing a reference to an rvalue?

Answer (score 2):

You cannot bind a non-`const` reference to a temporary.  The result of `(char *)newNode` is a temporary (it doesn't have a name).

You can, however, bind a `const` reference to a temporary.  So redeclaring your function as `writePage(long &pageNumber, char* const &node)` would work.

Comment: Though, the point of passing it by reference was probably to modify it so making it `const` might defeat the purpose.

Comment: Technical side node: "_You cannot bind a non-const reference to a temporary_" Actually, there is no temporary here!

Comment: @curiousguy: What is the result of a cast, then?

Comment: @OliCharlesworth "temporary" is the adjective, the noun implied here is "object". There is no object here. "_What is the result of a cast,_" an rvalue.

Answer (score 1):

What does `writePage` do? Are you in control of that function as well? Redeclaring the second parameter as `const` might help, if it does not write to this address. If it does—and its name suggests that somehow—it might be reasonable to use `Node*`in it anyway, i.e. declare it as

```
writePage(long &pageNumber, Node* &node)
```

After all, you don't want your `Node` pointer `newNode` to point to something which is not a `Node` instance at all, anymore, because it was overwritten by arbitrary `char`s. Do you?